# I want to create a ggplot scatter plot with 4 variables (3 continuous variables and 1 factorial variable)

Tags: r, ggplot2

[ggplot with three variables would like to add a fourth variable, as a point shape, which is a factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3mEV.png)
This is my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Dim.1, y=Dim.2, color= soilph, shape= imputedsoil))
```

dimensions 1 and 2 and soil pH are continuous.

`imputed` is a two-level factor.

This is the error code I receive:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (135): colour
```

Any help you could give would be appreciated, I can't find any advice online for a four-variable 'ggplot' where one of the '**extra**' variables is a factor and one is continuous.

Here is a small sample of my data created using the dput function:

```r
structure(list(Dim.1 = c(-0.826779300424281, -0.826779300424281, 
-0.826779300424281, -0.826779300424281, -0.826779300424281, -0.826779300424281, 
-0.826779300424281, -0.826779300424281, 3.13077029175822, 3.07814447486786, 
3.89869453739013, 2.63240937463108, 2.78203007023669, 3.57985580551222, 
-1.74653115781836, -1.74653115781836), Dim.2 = c(-2.21180913915791, 
-2.21180913915791, -2.21180913915791, -2.21180913915791, -2.21180913915791, 
-2.21180913915791, -2.21180913915791, -2.21180913915791, 1.41212418127028, 
1.30760054372476, 0.865339639945497, 1.07343354599186, 1.20882751794457, 
0.739609579390227, -3.87761036488784, -3.87761036488784), imputedsoil = c("Imputed", 
"Imputed", "Imputed", "Imputed", "Imputed", "Imputed", "Imputed", 
"Imputed", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", 
"Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing", "Not Missing"), 
    soilph = c(6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 6.92, 
    7.16, 7.43, 7.13, 7.16, 7.43, 7.13, 4.81, 4.81)), row.names = c("46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hello, try to provide example of your data, for example with `dput()`

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting I've added a small sample of my data

Comment: The `ggplot()` code you gave is just missing `+ geom_point()`. I added that and your plot code works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thank you that is the problem! I'm obviously going blind!